# Uploaded website on server but HTML link pages showing error

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

I have designed a website and uploaded it successfully on a server. The HTML pages links is no more working.

The website is www.rentacar-mauritius.com the "Home" works well but the other ones do not like "Tours, Rent a Car" and so on. By viewing my source on the browser, you'll see my code.

Comment: Can you share the link code?

Comment: Please note that questions in the form of "please see my website" are off-topic here, since once the problem is fixed (or the site goes offline) then future readers cannot learn from the question.

Answer (score 2):

Live server is **case sensitive** (Linux Hosting)

> I change your URL to `http://www.rentacar-mauritius.com/Rentacar.html` and **its working**

Check your file name(s), **Spellings**

so your URL(s)

```
http://www.rentacar-mauritius.com/rentacar.html
http://www.rentacar-mauritius.com/tours.html
http://www.rentacar-mauritius.com/gallery.html
http://www.rentacar-mauritius.com/about.html
http://www.rentacar-mauritius.com/contact.html
```

should be

```
http://www.rentacar-mauritius.com/Rentacar.html
http://www.rentacar-mauritius.com/Tours.html
http://www.rentacar-mauritius.com/Gallery.html
http://www.rentacar-mauritius.com/About.html
http://www.rentacar-mauritius.com/Contact.html
```

Like wise check your whole site

```
<a href="Rentacar.html">Rent A Car</a>
```

Comment: This is correct - some file-systems are case-sensitive which is why your URLs work on your dev machine, but not on the live server.

Comment: how noob of me :) i am not so good at coding but still guys :) thks a lot! :)

Comment: @Abdulla now i am editing the names and upload and check it...and will reply to you asap

Comment: Abdullah yes the server`s file-systems are case-sensitive...thks a lot man tomorrow i`ll do the changes on the server :) (y)

Comment: @ThomasWeb If this help please **[ACCEPT** it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

Filenames are case-sensitive for Linux environment. If your hosting server is running Linux, make sure that your file names match the href values exactly (including the case).